# Let V be a vector space over $Z_3$ and dim(V)=3 ,then V has how many elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

The following question is part of a mock test which I am trying to solve and I need help in this question.

> Let V be a vector space over $Z_3$ and dim(V)=3 ,then V has how many elements?

I used formula $(3^3 -1) (3^3 -3) (3^3 -3^2)$ but answer is given 125 elements.

I am asking here because I am not good in this type of questions so that you can tell me whether I am wrong and what is the right approach.

thnaks!!

Comment: When the answer was $125$, was the question over $\mathbb Z_{\color{red}5}$?

Comment: The formula you used counts the number of bases of $V$, not the number of elements.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No it was $\mathbb{Z}_3$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vector space will be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3^3$, which has $\vert\mathbb Z_3\vert^3=3^3=27$ elements

Comment: and the formula which I used should be used for what ?

Comment: That question was already answered in the comments by Andreas Blass: It's the number of different bases of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a basis consisting of three elements, and the base field has order three, there will be $3^3=27$ total linear combinations.